# Fading in and out at the same time between images dynamically(ish) using JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this wouldn't work. It seems to be immediately switching to the next image then fading in and out on that image and not between images. Any help would be awesome?

```
    <div id="slider">
    <img src="slider/1.jpg" id="test"></img>
    <div style="padding-bottom: 2%;">                       
    <button onClick="slider(1)" class="lebutt">1m</button>
    <button onClick="slider(2)" class="lebutt">50km</button>
    <button onClick="slider(3)" class="lebutt">the moon</button>
    <button onClick="slider(4)" class="lebutt">mars</button>
    <script>
    function slider(x) {                                                    
    var images = $('#slider img');  
    var y = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('src').slice(7,8);
    now = images.attr('src', "slider/" + y + ".jpg"); 
    last = now.filter(':visible');
    last.fadeOut();
    next = images.attr('src', "slider/" + x + ".jpg");
    next.fadeIn();
    }
    </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: In the HTML shown there is only one `<img>` element, so you can't fade in and out "at the same time" as in a cross-fade effect. You *can* fade out, then change the `src`, then fade in - would that be good enough?

Comment: I [setup JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pv6vq0b/), it looks like working.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: The question now would be how do I hide the first element and then show the second. I think I can figure it out though

Comment: @AmitKB Mine is definitely not doing that and it's the same code???

Comment: @AaronAnnuscheit I have modified the image 'src' attribute to pull a dummy image. Provide your images or setup similar test environment.

Comment: So I used your image src's and it did the same thing.

Comment: Is it possible that it is just because it isn't online yet?